# Java, нужен таймер, который срабатывает в определённое время

Tags: java, время

Простая задача - есть код, который должен быть запущен в определённый день, в определённое время(к примеру, завтра в 12:00), как это лучше всего реализовать на Java?

Comment: Масса вариантов: начиная от системных планировщиков и заканчивая циклом с проверкой текущего времени.

Comment: `Timer.shedule(TimerTask, Date)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29

Comment: `LockSupport.parkUntil()` — самый хакерский вариант =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Могу порекомендовать реализацию от Spring: [TaskScheduler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.0.0.M3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html)

Вот пример, как это может выглдядеть у вас в коде:

```
final String cronExpression = "* * * * * *";
final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler poolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
poolTaskScheduler.initialize();
poolTaskScheduler.schedule(() -> methodToBeExecuted(), new CronTrigger(cronExpression));
```

Метод methodToBeExecuted() будет выполяться каждую секунду. Периодичность выполнения можно настроить с помощью [cron-expressions](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger). Есть и другие готовые триггеры, которые могут вам помочь.